# How to find elements between MergedCells

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlsx

I have an .xlsx format table

Ive imported it into google docs:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rlyuBgs_LtRRp5aBFUjyqVmP3Lg0snETeWnvXadZ35o

The table may change daily. The item's data and their amount in this table can change, but the headers (category name, for ex "Processors"/"Motherboards", which r placed in MergedCells) remain unchanged.

I need to receive data by row between categories from .xlsx file with Openpyxl. But its necessary to understand which category these items belong to.

Ive tried to receive .coordinate from merged cells but these cells have no 'coordinate' attribute.
Please help me figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see [**`pandas`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/static/img/pandas_white.svg) tag but in case you're interested, here is proposition using this library to make an Excel workbook with multiple sheets that refer to the items of each category. We'll use [**`pandas.read_excel`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) to read the original Excel file, then select the items and finally create a new Excel file by using [**`pandas.ExcelWriter`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) with a context manger.

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.read_excel("example.xlsx", header=None, skiprows=[0],
                  usecols= "A,D:F", names=["ID", "Information", "Price", "Guarantee"])

list_of_categories= ["Processors", "Motherboards"]

df.insert(0, "Category", np.where(df["ID"].isin(list_of_categories), df["ID"], None))
df["Category"].ffill(inplace=True)
df["Price"]= df["Price"].round(2)
df.dropna(inplace=True)

with pd.ExcelWriter("example_retouche.xlsx") as writer:
    for category, sub_df in df.groupby("Category", sort=False):
        sub_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name= category, index=False)
```

Feel free to put different headers in `names` and to add more categories to `list_of_categories`.

##### # Output (Excel file):

[image]